# AsyncTask cannot modify UIThread after changing from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ui-thread

In my application I start an `AsyncTask` to download some data, and on the UI thread I start a `ProgressDialog`. The problem is when I change from portrait to landscape or vice versa, on the `onPostExecute` of the task I cannot dismiss the `ProgressDialog`. The `dismiss()` function is called over the instance of the `ProgressDialog`, but it doesn't dismiss. Why is that?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I think I lose the reference of the current activity in the AsyncTask thread. Is this possible? And if it is, how do I fix it?

**EDIT :**
Can't I keep a reference of the asyncTask and put it in the bundle?

Comment: are you calling your `AsyncTask` in `OnCreate` or in which part of your Activity.

Comment: Yes, but if I flip from portrait to landscape, it is not started again, because I save in the bundle of the current activity a boolean value which tells me if I started the asyncTask or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `android:configChanges` attribute of your activity to make it not recreating when switching orientation.

Comment: isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Ok, please explain how do I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Handler separately in onPostExecute method to dismiss the ProgressDialog as below:

```
    private Handler finishedHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Progressdialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't there a solution in which I can keep a reference somehow to the asyncTask, and I don't have to modify the `android:configChanges`?

Comment: please note that `<application>` doesn't have an `android:configChanges` attribute.

Comment: you need to set that in `Activity` Tag of your Activity.